# Using Windows Defender on Windows Server 2012R2 & 2016

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016, anti-virus

We have to renew our Anti-Virus licensing with McAffee.
However, we only have a handful of Windows Servers (2012R2 & 2016) that are running as a DC, Exchange, Backup and File server.
Would it be a good idea to use Windows Defender on all servers instead?

My search into this topic found out that some people are not happy with the performance of Windows Defender on Servers. However, these claims are from topics years ago.

This is not a critical online business. The servers and PCs here are only of secondary value for the company.

Comment: `The servers and PCs here are only of secondary value for us` and the rest of your network?

Comment: Windows Defender is only available in Windows Server 2012 R2 for Server Core installations.

Comment: @Lenniey for us i mean the company, I updated my question to include your remark.

Comment: Yes. Read my comment more carefully. I said Windows Server 2012 R2. In Windows Server 2012 and Windows Server 2012 R2 it's only available in Server Core installations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it, some tell it detect less treats, but it’s to test. If you intend to use Windows Defender, I would opt to get the SKU to be able to install the Windows Defender ATP console.

That way you will have a global view of the health of your IT park.

The doc about the console; https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-atp/portal-overview-windows-defender-advanced-threat-protection

The doc about onboarding server, as the default doc talk only about Windows 10; https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-atp/configure-server-endpoints-windows-defender-advanced-threat-protection

Comment: Thank you for your response. We will look in to the ATP console.